# Concurrent read and delete on GridFs - MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using Gridfs MongoDb C# driver in order to store large files on Mongo.
I have a particular situation in which one or more client download a file while another process is trying to delete this file.
What happens in this situation? Will the reading clients receive a corrupted file (some chunk will be missed) or will receive an error from the drivers?

I'm trying to allow concurrent read and write operations on a file stored in MongoDb Gridfs keeping the read results consistent.